# How can I extend D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there an API for extending D3 like with jQuery? With jQuery we are able to extend it like this:

```
$.fn.myExtnesion = function () {  
    return $(this).each(function myPlugincode(){
    });
};
```

Is there a similar API for D3?

Comment: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/06/extending-d3-js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to add functions directly to the various D3 object prototypes, we've used this in the library I am building to add functions to [d3 selections for example](https://github.com/ScottLogic/d3fc/blob/7b71aec0223d850e5d4489ecb8dd18d4f6e4cedb/src/layout/layout.js#L102).

For example:

```
d3.selection.prototype.layout = function() {
   // your code goes here, where 'this' is the D3 selection
}
```