# How to warp d3 "translate" into a function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3, to move an object to a designated position, it is usually done with:

```
g_x.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
```

How can I warp it into a function (or method?) call which can be used like this:

```
g_x.move(x, y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is extending D3 prototypes, I'm sure someone will post an answer along these lines shortly.

However, I believe that the easiest solution is using [call](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_call), which:

> Invokes the specified function exactly once, passing in this selection along with any optional arguments.

So, in your case, let's create a function named `move`:

```
function move(selection, x, y) {
    selection.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
};
```

For translating a selection by `100,100`, for instance, we can use:

```
selection.call(move, 100, 100);
```

Here is a demo, the circle is originally at `10,10`, and after 1 second it's translated by `100,100`:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");
setTimeout(() => {
  circle.call(move, 100, 100)
}, 1000);

function move(selection, x, y) {
  selection.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="8" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**: using a very simple and crude example of an extended D3 prototype:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");

setTimeout(() => {
  circle.move(100, 100)
}, 1000);

d3.selection.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
  return this;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="8" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. If I want to extend the prototype, should I do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675769/how-can-i-extend-d3 ? I.e. d3.selection.prototype.move = function() {} ?

Comment: Yes. This post gives a more detailed explanation: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/06/extending-d3-js/

Comment: It seems the following works. d3.selection.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
        this.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        return this;
    };

Comment: Yes, it works, I added it to the answer. It could be more elaborate, though: extending the "enter" selection as well, testing for arguments, working as a getter (right now it's only a setter) etc...